# How to read Health app vital data into other apps in ios using Healthkit

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am using iHealth devices to get the vitals from device using there iHealth app,those data is stored in Health app. I have configured my application to communicate with Health app but I have no idea how to get the stored data of health to my own custom app.

As there are no examples for this issue and the documentation also didn't provide in-depth information about it.

Comment: The HealthKit video from this years WWDC is very helpful! https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#203

Answer (score 0):

As long as you (or the user) of your app has granted access to your app to read what iHealth has stored in the HealthKit database, you can query it with the HealthKit APIs.

```
// 1. these are the items we want to read
let healthKitTypesToRead = NSSet(array:[
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose)
])

// 2. these are the items we want to write
let healthKitTypesToWrite = NSSet(array:[
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose)
])

// 3.  Request HealthKit authorization
    healthKitStore!.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in

            if( completion != nil )
            {
                if (success == true) {
                    self.initialized = true
                }
                completion(success:success,error:error)
            }
    }
```

Then you can query for the data:

```
// 4. Build the Predicate
let past = NSDate.distantPast() as NSDate
let now   = NSDate()
let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(past, endDate:now, options: .None)

    //  Build the sort descriptor to return the samples in descending order
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    //  we want to limit the number of samples returned by the query to just 1 (the most recent)
    let limit = 1

    //  Build samples query
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: mostRecentPredicate, limit: limit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
        { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

            if let queryError = error {
                completion(nil,error)
                return;
            }

            // Get the first sample
            let mostRecentSample = results.first as? HKQuantitySample

            // Execute the completion closure
            if completion != nil {
                completion(mostRecentSample,nil)
            }
    }
    // 5. Execute the Query
    self.healthKitStore!.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, After enable Healthkit in your AppID.You have to authenticate require from health store.

```
let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

    func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void)!)
    {

        // 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
        var healthKitTypesToRead = self.dataTypesToRead() as! Set<NSObject>

        // 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
        var healthKitTypesToWrite = self.dataTypesToWrite() as! Set<NSObject>


        // 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
        if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
        {
            let error = NSError(domain: "com.domain.....", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"HealthKit is not available in this Device"])
            if( completion != nil )
            {
                completion(success:false, error:error)
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {

             // 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
            healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes:healthKitTypesToRead, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if( completion != nil )
                {
                    completion(success:success,error:error)
                }

            })


        }

    }
```

Useful link as below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_%28application%29

http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#203